# Putting Geo Ip into a database Problem PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ip

Hey, I know the title is really bad...I didn't know what else to say. Well anyways, I have a website that I want to track their ip and geo address ip, and found this snippet from CSS-Tricks, http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/get-geo-ip-information/ 
I got that working, and the return was `Array ( [domain] => dslb-094-219-040-096.pools.arcor-ip.net [country] => DE - Germany [state] => Hessen [town] => Fl�rsheim )`.

---

I have made a table and want to disect that array and put city into one mysql row, country into another one, and domain into another one. Can anyone help me make a mysql insert that inserts all of these different datas into each corresponding mysql row?

Thanks for all help...I have just recently started learning php, so I am still quite of a beginner.

Comment: What is the problem? Is it "how to access the array components" or "how do I insert something into my DB"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the geoCheckIP already returns an array ([read more](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)), you can do as follow:

```
$geoData = geoCheckIP($ip);
```

And you would read each value like:

```
$geoData["domain"]
$geoData["country"]
$geoData["state"]
$geoData["town"]
```

And a MySQL insert for this would be something like:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users_data` (`domain`, `country`, `state`, `town`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($geoData["domain"]), mysql_real_escape_string($geoData["country"]), mysql_real_escape_string($geoData["state"]), mysql_real_escape_string($geoData["town"]));
```

[More on mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

[More on php and mysql](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)